# Aws communication between lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

What is the best approach when I want to have a two AWS lambdas talk to each other?

I want one lambda to be called by users in my cognito pool but the other lambda should only be called by my first lambda.

Should i utilise a message queue, or how can i properly call into my other lambda as a rest endpoint?

Comment: Google 'synchronous and asynchronous invocation AWS lambda' as a first starting point; the answer here is 'it depends'.

Comment: What do you mean by "one lambda to be called by users in my cognito pool"?

Answer (score 2):

An AWS Lambda function can `Invoke()` another AWS Lambda function.

Please note that the two Lambda functions do not "communicate with" or "talk to" each other. Rather, one function calls the AWS Lambda service with the `Invoke` API call, asking it to run the other Lambda function. The result of the second Lambda function will then be returned as a response to the Invoke request.